# When is the Lie bracket of two root spaces nonzero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a semisimple Lie algebra with root space decomposition $L = L_0 \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in \Phi} L_\alpha$. For roots $\alpha, \beta \in \Phi$, we always have $[L_\alpha, L_\beta] \subseteq L_{\alpha + \beta}$.

I know how to show that $[L_{\alpha}, L_{-\alpha}]$ is nonzero. In other cases, when can we guarantee that $[L_\alpha, L_\beta]$ is nonzero assuming that $\alpha + \beta$ is also a root? This feels like it should be really important in recovering a semisimple Lie algebra from its root system, but I have been unable to find a simple answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is always true**; in fact, $[L_\alpha, L_\beta] = L_{\alpha+\beta}$ for any two roots $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\alpha+\beta$ is a root (which by definition entails that $L_{\alpha+\beta} \neq 0$).

It holds in particular if your semisimple Lie algebra is split, i.e. you defined your roots via some Cartan subalgebra consisting of ad-diagonalisable matrices (as is automatically the case e.g. over $\mathbb C$), and where it turns out all root spaces are one-dimensional. But it even holds in the more general case that you defined your (possibly non-reduced) root system via [some maximal split toral subalgebra (which might not be a maximal toral = Cartan subalgebra)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1071417/96384), where root spaces might have dimension $\ge 2$.

In any case it's a good question, because the proof I know uses, even in the split case, a little more "well-known" theory than one might expect.

**Hint 1**: In the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, it is well-known that the eigenvalues of $h := \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$ on a finite-dimensional representation $V$ are all integers $\lambda$, and of course we have a decomposition $V \simeq \bigoplus V_\lambda$ into corresponding eigenspaces. It is further well-known, but the crucial fact for what you want, that *if both $\lambda$ and $\lambda +2$ are such eigenvalues*, then (EDIT: thanks @Joppy for pointing out there was a mistake here earlier, I hope it's good now)

- for $\lambda \ge -1$, the element $x :=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ maps $V_\lambda$ *surjectively* onto $V_{\lambda+2}$
- for $\lambda \le -1$, the element $x :=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ maps $V_\lambda$ *injectively* into $V_{\lambda+2}$

**Hint 2**: $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triples. More precisely, you want an $h_\alpha$ in your maximal split toral subalgebra (= Cartan subalgebra if we're in the split case) with $\beta(h_\alpha)= \check{\alpha}(\beta)$, and a good $x_\alpha \in L_\alpha$, and consider $V:=\sum_{i \in \mathbb Z} L_{\beta + i \alpha}$ as an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-representation.

Now hint 2 together with just the "surjective" part of hint 1 gives the assertion for $\check{\alpha}(\beta) \ge -1$. However, if that is not the case, then we can just flip the roles of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (because of $\alpha \neq -\beta$, at least one of $\check{\alpha}(\beta)$ and $\check{\beta}(\alpha)$ is always $\ge -1$, even in the case of non-reduced root systems), and still get $[L_{\beta}, L_{\alpha}]=[L_{\alpha}, L_{\beta}]=L_{\alpha+\beta}$.

If we are in the split case, i.e. our maximal split toral subalgebra equals its own centralizer $L_0$, then the same idea proves that *all root spaces $L_\alpha$ are one-dimensional*: because $ad(x_\alpha):L_0 \rightarrow L_\alpha$ is surjective, but by definition has image spanned by $x_\alpha$. (Then the "injective" part of hint 1 together with hint 2 again suffices to conclude in general, even without flipping $\alpha$ and $\beta$.)

For the split case, compare also the answers to [Why are root spaces of root decomposition of semisimple Lie algebra 1 dimensional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1082159/96384) and [How to show this $L$-module is simple? (related to the root space decomposition of semisimle Lie algebras)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3135978/96384).

Comment: If both $\lambda$ and $\lambda + 2$ are eigenvalues, *and* if $V$ is irreducible, then $x$ gives an isomorphism $V_\lambda$ to $V_{\lambda + 2}$, but this need not be true if $V$ is not irreducible. Take the adjoint representation plus the trivial for instance, then $V_{-2}$ is one-dimensional and $V_0$ is two-dimensional.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Just to clarify, when you say in the beginning that $[L_\alpha, L_\beta] = L_{\alpha + \beta}$, you mean that this is true for any semisimple Lie algebra over any field and the root system can come from maximal split toral subalgebra (as is the case when dealing with symmetric spaces)? Can you give references in books/papers which contain such statements and proofs? Thanks.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar: Any field **of characteristic $0$** (in positive char., weird things happen), but otherwise yes to that generality. The closest reference I know is Prop 3.1.13(i) of my own thesis, which translated to our notation here would say: For any roots $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\alpha+ \beta$ is a root, $\check{\alpha}(\beta) \ge -1$ implies $[X_\alpha, L_\beta] = L_{\alpha+\beta}$ for all $0 \neq X_\alpha \in L_\alpha$. This is somewhat stronger, once one knows that one of $\check{\alpha}(\beta)$ or $\check{\beta}(\alpha)$ *is* $\ge -1$, as per all standard sources on root systems.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you! I was interested in this from symmetric spaces (so over $\mathbb R$). So the situation in general is the same as in the rank one case which is known by more explicit characterizations (Strong Rigidity of Locally Symmetric Spaces by Mostow).