$k \alpha$ is a root implies $k = \pm 1$.
This is a doubt about proof given in section 21.1, Fulton and Harris.
Authors consider the representation $$i = \oplus_k g_{k\alpha}$$ of the Lie algebra $ s_{\alpha} \cong sl_2 \mathbb C.$
I understand all non zero factors but $g_0$ are one dimensional. Then authors assume that $\alpha$ is the smallest non zero root that appears in the string. What they mean by smallest root? Is it a root having minimal length ?
Then they decompose $i$ as direct sum of $ s_{\alpha} $ and $i'$.
How to check that $i'$ has no eigen space with eigen value $1$ or $2$ for $H_{\alpha}?$ Then how it follows that $i'$ must be trivial? Can anyone explain?

When you looked through e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1082159/96384 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/476423/96384, and related questions linked to those, did you find anything useful?
